# How to get the value of the div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mean-stack

I am using JQUERY in my angularjs project since in some special conditions(AMP).

```
 <div data-ng-repeat = "comment in blog.comments">
       <i class="icon-edit font20 edit-faq-icon pointer" id="edit-comment" data-ng-click="editComment(comment);"></i>
  </div>
```

Previously I had ng-click and now I can only find event by jquery.

```
$('#edit-comment').click(function(){
  alert('hi');
})
```

But I want to access the parameter passed(`comment`) in the function `editComment(comment)`.

Comment: You can put the value of the `comment` in a hidden field and then you can call `$('#hidden-field').val()` to get that value

Answer (score 0):

Write a scope function in your angular controller like the below function. You will get the comment as parameter.

```
$scope.editComment=function(comment)
 {
 $scope.comment=comment;
};
```

Set an html content like this.

```
<div ng-model="comment" id="Comment"></div>
```

Now you can use 
$('#Comment').val()  to get the value in click

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.text()** method to get the value of div.
also you can refer the following link **http://api.jquery.com/text/**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comment by passing the comment as a parameter to ng-click function.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCntrlr",function($scope){
    $scope.blog=
      {
        name:"Naresh",
        comments:["test comment 1","test comment 2","test comment 3"]
      }
      
      $scope.editComment = function(comm){
       alert(comm);
      };
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js'></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrlr">
<div ng-repeat = "comment in blog.comments">
       <button ng-click="editComment(comment);">get Comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```